# Bootstrap issue with form elements not being responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using forms on my website that uses bootstrap, however when I re-size the site horizontally I am finding that all elements on the website are behaving as expected and resizing as the width is reduced.

Here is the link: http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/wp/contact/

However the form elements are not resizing to fit the window as it resizes. To illustrate the issue:

[image]

Comment: You need to put some `spanX` class on them.

Comment: I'm looking at this now and it certainly isn't breaking through the responsive grid in Chrome. Have you already solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this myself before with Bootstrap.  For the most part, the form input fields have a set-width on them out of Bootstrap, which doesn't account for who wide their parents are.  This means that it is possible to get the situation exactly as you're seeing where they flow wider than they should.

I tend to tackle this on a case-by-case (ie: project-by-project) basis, given that forms are inevitably always laid out slightly differently each time and tweak the form input withs sepcifically at each break point (down to the phone/tablet inbetweeny fluid width where I just allow them all to go fluid).

From looking at your preview link, it's worth mentioning that you appear to have some JavaScript in there somewhere (possibly in the WP plugin you're using to make the contact form) which is changing the width of your inputs on the fly, rather than relying on your CSS.

[image: screenshot]

It looks to be behaving OK, although you might come across problems with the date-select fields because of their (quite wide) widths when placed side-by-side like that.